# Google Endpoints GET request URL parameters [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am currently working on a small project where I need to write a GET handler. I am working from the Echo example provided in the endpoints documentation.

I have my resource container:

```
GET_EMAIL_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    i = messages.IntegerField(1, default = 1)
)
```

And I have my handler:

```
@endpoints.method(
    GET_EMAIL_RESOURCE,
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo/getEmails/{i}',
    http_method='GET',
    name='echo_get_emails'
)
def echo_get_emails(self, request):
    if (request.i == 1):
        out = "default"
    else:
        out = "a"*request.i
    return EchoResponse(content=out)
```

And to access this I am using curl:

```
curl --request GET --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo/getEmails/3
```

Now this works fine and returns what you expect, but if I need to encode more information into my URL such as:

```
getEmails/value1=someValue&value2=someOtherValue
```

I cannot figure out how to do this and I am unable to find an explanation or example in the docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

My code now looks like so:

```
# main.py

GET_EMAIL_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    i = messages.IntegerField(1, default = 1)
)

@endpoints.method(
    GET_EMAIL_RESOURCE,
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo/getEmails',
    http_method='GET',
    name='echo_get_emails'
)
def echo_get_emails(self, request):
    out = str(request.trailingDigits) + " : " +str(request.leadingDigits)
    return EchoResponse(content = out)
```

and in my openapi.json under the path I have:

```
"/echo/v1/echo/getEmails" : {
  "get": {
    "operationId": "EchoApi_getEmails",
    "parameters" : [
      {
        "name": "trailingDigits",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "Trailing digits",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "leadingDigits",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "Leading digits",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Yet when I run the request
    curl --request GET --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo/getEmails?trailingDigits=2&leadingDigits=2

I get back the contents of trailingDigits but the default for leadingDigits

Answer (score 0):

Any fields in a `ResourceContainer` not used in the `path` value should become query parameters.

Comment: But then how would I access the query parameter? so I have the path getEmails?value1=someValue but how do I access value1 from my method? I cannot find any information about this in the docs

Comment: If your `ResourceContainer` has `value1 = messages.StringField(1)` then your handler would just do `request.value1`.

Comment: I have that working fine, but what about multiple values? for instance in my `ResourceContainer` I have `trailingDigits = messages.IntegerField(1, default = 1, required=True), leadingDigits = messages.IntegerField(2, default = 1, required=True)` and when I run the query `getEmail?trailingDigits=7&leadingDigits=5` the trailingDigits works but the leadingDigits doesn't seem to capture a value.

Comment: I imagine that's a bug. If you don't mind filing a bug at https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python that would be great.

Comment: I feel like it would be more likely that there is something wrong in my code due to the fact that this is a very simple thing that should have come up as a bug previously, if this doesn't get resolved I will post a bug report, but I am hesitant to do so until I know if it is a bug or now.

I have edited the main post to show the changes I have made and the progress since the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify parameters you need to configure the openapi.json file for the desired path. Here’s an example:

```
"/echo/v1/echo/test": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "test",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "paramOne",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "First parameter test",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
          },
          {
            "name": "paramTwo",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Second parameter test",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
          }
         ]
```

[Here](https://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject)'s some useful documentation.

**EDIT 1:**

Once you edited the params in the openapi.json file, you need to adapt the Python code to use those new params.

In this case you’ll need to adapt the ResourceContainer to accept a second argument.

Here’s an example:

```
YOUR_RESOURCE_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
message_types.VoidMessage,
parameter1=messages.IntegerField(1, default=1),
parameter2=messages.IntegerField(2, default=2))
```

One thing to keep in mind: when using curl remember to add "" to the url. Not using it may cause the call to malfunction.

Comment: I set that up in my openapi.json and get the problem, I am editing the post to show what I have now done

Comment: Hi @AnthonyO'Brien I just edited the answer accordingly to your last update

Answer (score 0):

This answer from Google forums fixed the issue for me:

> Are you using quotes around the URL in your curl command? Because if
>   not, and you're in a bash shell (which is pretty likely if you're
>   using curl), you might  not actually be *sending* the &ends_at=THEEND
>   part, because & is a  shell metacharacter to put the command in the
>   background.

**Edit**

Link to the answer in forum
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/uzFcUS_uNz0/xyG2qVxbBQAJ

Comment: You might add the forum's url to your post. So other users can follow up.