# Allow repeated field in gRPC Transcoding

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc-python

I'm using `gRPC` in **Google CLoud Endpoints** I'm using quick example for [endpoint python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started-grpc)
I addition one function for `SayHelloRepeated` but don't know how to transcode repeated field.

**helloworld.proto**

```
service Greeter {
...

rpc SayHelloRepeated (RepeatedHello) returns (HelloReply) {}

...
}

message RepeatedHello {
repeated HelloRequest hello_request = 1;
}

message HelloRequest {
string name = 1;
}
```

**api_config_http.yaml**

```
http:
rules:
    ...

    - selector: helloworld.Greeter.SayHelloRepeated
    get: /v1/rsayhello/{hello_request}

    ...
```

When I try to deploy `api_config_http.yaml` it give me error **Repeated field not allowed**

> ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
>
> kind: ERROR
>   message: "http: repeated field not allowed: reached via \'hello_request\' on message \'helloworld.RepeatedHello\'."

**Update**

What If `HelloRequest` has multiple fields not just the one `name` field then what to do.

```
message HelloRequest {
string name = 1;
string message = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation [Package google.api](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api):

> Each mapping specifies a URL path template and an HTTP method. The path template may refer to one or more fields in the gRPC request message, as long as each field is a non-repeated field with a primitive (non-message) type.

This means that you **can't** use a repeated field in the gRPC. So, you can't use this exact format for you to use repeated fields.

I would recommend you to check this part of the documentation - [gRPC Transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api#grpc-transcoding) - to get more information on how to perform a workaround to achieve the use of repeated fields.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi @AzeemHaider could you please take a look at this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775802/google-endpoints-get-request-url-parameters-python)? I believe it should provide you some assistance, since the user's problem seems to be similar to your, regarding passing multiple values via GET.

Comment: I checked it but it is using openapi.yaml I'm using gRPC. Still not able to get any idea how can I pass repeated field in. Can you please show me any example.

Comment: Hi @AzeemHaider as I mentioned in my answer, unfortunately, there isn't a way to use repeated field in gRPC. However, in this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api#grpc-transcoding), you should found information on how to workaround it. Could you please check it?